# Why am I getting this error "Invalid opcode 0x002E at PC=0x0006"

Tags: c

```
#include<lpc214x.h>
#define bit(x) (1<<x)
#define delay for(i=0;i<7000;i++);
 
#define RAIN (IO1PIN & (1<<24))
 
unsigned int i;
 
void lcd_int();
void dat(unsigned char);
void cmd(unsigned char);
void string(unsigned char *);
 
void main()
{
    IO0DIR =0XFFF;
    IO1DIR = 0x0;
    lcd_int();
    cmd(0x80);
    string("RAIN ");
    while(1) {
            if(RAIN == 0) {
                    string("Rain Detected");
                    //You can also add alarm here
            }
            delay;delay;
            cmd(0x01);
        }
}
 
void lcd_int()
{
    cmd(0x38);
    cmd(0x0c);
    cmd(0x06);
    cmd(0x01);
    cmd(0x80);
}
 
void cmd(unsigned char a)
{
    IO0PIN&=0x00;
    IO0PIN|=(a<<0);
    IO0CLR|=bit(8);                //rs=0
    IO0CLR|=bit(9);                //rw=0
    IO0SET|=bit(10);               //en=1
    delay;
    IO0CLR|=bit(10);               //en=0
}
 
void dat(unsigned char b)
{
    IO0PIN&=0x00;
    IO0PIN|=(b<<0);
    IO0SET|=bit(8);                //rs=1
    IO0CLR|=bit(9);                //rw=0
    IO0SET|=bit(10);               //en=1
    delay;
    IO0CLR|=bit(10);               //en=0
}
 
void string(unsigned char *p)
{
    while(*p!='\0') {
        dat(*p++);
    }
}
```

This i the hex file for my rain sensor simulation using LPC2138 in proteus. But when i ad it to the microproccessor and run the program it gives me the error saying "Invalid opcode 0x002E at PC=0x0006". I have also attatched a photo of the proteus simulation[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Cbm.png)

Comment: do you compile it before "adding"?

Comment: Did you add the hex file by entering "Edit Properties" on the LPC2138 and configuring "Program File" as the C file that you have written, that you've copied on your answer?

Comment: @gulpr yes i compiled the program

Comment: @Schilive yea thats what i did

Comment: @GKrishnan, is the text that you have copied in your answer the compiled program or the code you have compiled?

Comment: Invalid op code most likely means invalid program format. I'm not quite following what "adding to the microprocessor" is supposed to mean - is that still in the simulator or in a live MCU? In case of the latter how did you download the program, in which format and through which tool?

Comment: @Lundin, I imagine it is in the simulator, since I don't think real microprocessor give out such errors, and by his comments. If so, then by "adding" I think he means to the microprocessor's properties menu on the simulator, which seems to accept .hex files.

Comment: @Schilive the text is the compiled program

Comment: @GKrishnan, the text in your answer is not compiled code, but it is code in the C programming language. A compiled program is a file containing machine instructions, though in varying formats, like .EXE. The emulator you are using probably needs compiled code in the .HEX format, probably Intel HEX. To do this, you need to use a compiler. >>